# Retrieve WRB soil classes by country

Tags: r, csv, soilgrids

I would like to retrieve the list of the different WRB soil classes by country (https://data.isric.org/geonetwork/srv/fre/catalog.search#/metadata/c4dc161c-d62d-11ea-a1a3-292680b15169).

I would like to get this data in order to know the diversity of soils by country.

Can you give me some line of thought ?

I looked for if a file (CSV format) exist but I did not find anything. Perhaps an R package like SoilGrids should be used in order to retrieve the list of the different classes by country.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the .tif files of soils classes you can read them in R as a raster `stack` and then use the `exact_extract` function from the `exactextractr` package, which is the fastest way around.
An example code:

```
library(exactextractr)  
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(sf)
## Example SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
data(wrld_simpl) #polygon of world countries
wrld_simpl_sf <- st_as_sf(wrld_simpl)

## Example RasterLayer
r <- raster(nrow=2e3, ncol=2e3, crs=proj4string(wrld_simpl), xmn=-180, xmx=180, 
        ymn=-90, ymx=90)

r[] <- sample(1:10,length(r),replace = T)

#plot, so you can see it
plot(r)    
plot(wrld_simpl, add=TRUE) 


ex <- exact_extract(r,wrld_simpl_sf))
```

Here I've simulated a single raster with all the soil classes (10 in the example). If you have one raster for each soil class you can read them together with `raster::stack` and then you can use the same identical code above for the extraction.
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example